# format String from a Pipe delimited string

Tags: java, string, netbeans

hey I have a string as such:

```
357902||190||RUE RACHELLE||ST|||LES CÈDRES|J7T1J9|QC
```

I wish to take the numbers right before the first PIPE delimter (reading from left to right)

and replace that PART of the string with another string I have..

than I wish to have a new constructed string with the replacement...

for example:

```
357902||190||RUE RACHELLE||ST|||LES CÈDRES|J7T1J9|QC
```

can turn into:

```
48949168||190||RUE RACHELLE||ST|||LES CÈDRES|J7T1J9|QC
```

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the simpliest solution is :

```
            String s1 = "357902||190||RUE RACHELLE||ST|||LES CÈDRES|J7T1J9|QC";
            String s2 = "48949168";
            System.out.println(s2+s1.substring(s1.indexOf("||")));
```

**Output** :

> 48949168||190||RUE RACHELLE||ST|||LES CÈDRES|J7T1J9|QC

`s1.substring(s1.indexOf("||")` gives you :

> ||190||RUE RACHELLE||ST|||LES CÈDRES|J7T1J9|QC

Answer (score 2):

You can split the string into 2 substrings, then concat your another string with the 2nd substring.

```
String s = "357902||190||RUE RACHELLE||ST|||LES CÈDRES|J7T1J9|QC";
String s1 = "48949168";
String a[] = s.split(s,2);
String b = s1+a[1];
System.out.println(b);
```

Comment: @GregKopff The 2nd argument will tell JVM to split the string to only 2 substrings. That means JVM will check the regex's first occurance and split the string from there. It will not check the further regex occurances in the string.

Comment: What I'm puzzled by is that the regex you supply to split() is the input string itself. How does that match only the required bit? (I don't use regexs much). Are you relying on the fact that the pipe delimiter is also a special regex character?

Answer (score 0):

```
String s2 = "357902||190||RUE RACHELLE||ST|||LES CÈDRES|J7T1J9|QC";
String s3 = "48949168";
System.out.println(s2.replaceAll(s2.substring(0,s2.indexOf("||")), s3));
```

Comment: `replaceAll` takes regex as arguments so if your substring result in an invalid pattern it will fail. It's a bit risky to use this here. THe other pb is if the substring equals `1` for example all the `1` will be replace. Not only the first part.